# Travel Visa for Mexico (residing in UAE) Indian Passport holder

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico, uae, residency

I hold an Indian passport however residing in UAE(Dubai) Visa of Employment, what are the documents needed to apply for Mexican visa for travel/tourism purpose?

Answer (score 2):

From https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos/index.php/es/2016-05-07-10-39-06 the documents needed to apply for a visitor visa are:

1.- Visa application fully filled with capital letters.

2.- Valid passport with at least two blank pages. Validity of at least six months prior to expiration.

3.- Passport photocopies of the first 3 pages and all valid visas.

4.- Two passport sized pictures of applicant on a white background (Uncovered head).

5.- Proof of economic solvency:

a) Letter from applicant’s employer stating salary, length of employment and position .

b) Statements of the applicant’s bank account of the last 3 months and photocopies.

c) International credit card (with an upper limit higher than one thousand USD) and photocopy.

d) Return plane ticket and photocopy

7.- The applicant has to be a resident in the United Arab Emirates

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply for a tourist visa for Mexico in the UAE if you are a resident there.

On the [list of requirements on the consulate of Mexico in the UAE website](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos/index.php/es/2016-05-07-10-39-06):

> 7. The applicant has to be a resident in the United Arab Emirates

So as long as you are a legal resident in the UAE you will be fine.